# Django squash or eliminate migrations on production

Tags: django, django-migrations

I have an app on production. It has 251 migrations that take too much time when I run the tests, it is making development really slow. I need to do something about this and I'd like an advice. Is it recommendable to squash the 251 migrations? what if I erase then and then just `fake initial`? of course, I can't lose or change the database, it is on production. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to squash them, but you will probably run into the `CircularDependencyError` mentioned here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/migrations/#squashing-migrations

Another option is to (make sure your database is backed up) remove all migration files, remove the data in the migrations table, make migrations again, migrate --with `--fake-initial` and hope everything still works -- obviously, try this in a development environment first, followed by a staging instance identical to your production server.

Comment: I did this and forgot to remove the data in the migrations table. I don't have easy access to it since it is on Heroku. Is there any problem if I don't erase the data in the migrations table? it worked just fine...

Comment: heroku's postgres instances are just like any other database, you can connect to them the same way you do in your app

Comment: There is also a nice tutorial about this method. See [here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/26/how-to-reset-migrations.html).